# Equation with parameter $a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $$y = {5a-15x+ax\over x^2-2ax+a^2+25}.$$ Find appropriate values of $a$ if $y$ must contain a gap $[0;1]$

I found incomplete values.
I'm confused, who can help

Comment: I'm confused too. What on earth does "Y must contain a gap" mean? Are you translating the question from a language other than English?

Comment: which values did you found ? Denominator is $(x-a)^2+25>0$ so $y$ is completely continuous.

Comment: @HenningMakholm If I had to hazard a guess, there are two things that it could mean: the function $y$ should be discontinuous at $x=0$ and $x=1$, or the function $y$ should be discontinuous over all values in $[0,1]$. Seeing as how a rational expression is "rarely" discontinuous at an uncountably infinite number of points (at least in the algebra-precalculus sequence), the case where we just consider $x\in\{0,1\}$ is probably the most logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed $a \in \mathbb{R}$, let

$$f(x) = \frac{5a-15x+ax}{x^2-2ax+a^2+25}$$

Since the denominator of $f$ is equal to

$$(x-a)^2 + 25$$

which is always positive, it follows that $f$ is continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

But you specified that you seek values of $a$ for which

$$\,\text{$y$ has a $``$gap$"$ in $[0,1]$}$$

I'll interpret that to mean that there is at least one element of $[0,1]$ which is not in the range of $f$.

Based on that interpretation, the analysis can proceed as follows . . .

If $a$ is such that both $0$ and $1$ are in the range of $f$, then since $f$ is continuous, the intermediate value theorem would guarantee that all elements of $[0,1]$ are in the range of $f$.

Thus, we want to find the values of $a$ such that at least one of the numbers $0,1$ is not in the range of $f$.

Setting $f(x) = 0$ and solving for $x$ yields

$$x=\frac{5a}{15-a}$$

so $0$ is not in the range of $f$ if and only if $a = 15$.

Setting $f(x) = 1$ and solving for $x$ yields

$$x=\frac{-15+3a \pm \sqrt{5a^2-70a+125}}{2}$$

so $1$ is not in the range of $f$ if and only if

$$5a^2-70a+125 < 0$$

which, by solving the above qudratic inequality, yields the condition

$$7-2\sqrt{6} < a < 7 + 2\sqrt{6}$$

Combining the results, we have

$$\text{$a$ is such that $y$ has a gap in $[0,1]$}$$
$$\text{if and only if}$$
$$a = 15\;\;\;\;\;\text{or}\;\;\;\;\;7-2\sqrt{6} < a < 7 + 2\sqrt{6}$$

Comment: Apparently I have explained the problem wrong. But I'm grateful to you for trying. And yes, i'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Btw you have done the task the exact opposite. Oy has that gap. Also answer is all values of A except your answer

Comment: @Chris Menschenin: I don't follow -- please explain.